# htmlspecialchars_decode() dosen't work with spaces

Tags: php, decode

I'm trying to use htmlspecialchars_decode() but it don't decoding `&nbsp;` into spaces. Are any solutions of this problem?

My code:

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from nowosci order by id desc limit 0,3");
while($rekord = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
$tekst .= '<h1 class="body"><div class="date" style="display:inline; color:grey; margin-right:5px;">'.$rekord[3].'</div>'.html_entity_decode($rekord[1]).'</h1><div class="main">'.html_entity_decode($rekord[2]).'</div>';
}
echo $tekst
```

Comment: You can't do a replace("&nbsp;", " ", $str); afterwards?

Comment: I'd double check what `$rekord[1]` and `$rekord[2]` contain by a `var_dump($rekord[1]);` and `var_dump($rekord[2]);`.

Answer (score 13):

Use `html_entity_decode()` instead.

`htmlspecialchars_decode()` only decodes `&amp; &quot; (when ENT_NOQUOTES is not set), &#039; (when ENT_QUOTES is set), &lt; and &gt;.`

Comment: @user192012, html_entity_decode() should decode `&nbsp;`. Are you sure the input string is not encoded twice?

Answer (score 4):

`htmlspecialchars_decode()` decodes `htmlspecialchars` and it's not supposed decode `&nbsp;` as this does not belong to `htmlspecialchars`. you can look at [htmlspecialchars list](http://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html).

you can use `html_entity_decode();` instead.