# PHP convert html &nbsp; to space, &gt; to > etc

Tags: php, html

I want to convert all html tags(&nbsp &gt &lt etc) to text format;
I have try

```
html_entity_decode()
```

but it will return  ?  if &nbsp.

Comment: Why don't you test? And also scroll down on the manual page because there are related functions listed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `htmlspecialchars_decode` is the opposite of `htmlspecialchars`. 

Example from the PHP documentation page:

```
    $str = '<p>this -&gt; &quot;</p>';
    echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str); 
    //Output: <p>this -> "</p>
```

Comment: @rikiless, RavatSinh's solution worked for me in removing all HTML tags, including &nbsp;.

Comment: this solution does not help with `&nbsp;`, please see link for details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737675/htmlspecialchars-decode-dosent-work-with-spaces

Comment: Use html_entity_decode() instead since htmlspecialchars_decode decodes only some characters. e.g. &nbsp; stays unchanged.

Answer (score 18):

[html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) is the opposite of [htmlentities()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) in that it converts all HTML entities in the string to their applicable characters.

```
$orig = "I'll \"walk\" the <b>dog</b> now";

$a = htmlentities($orig);

$b = html_entity_decode($a);

echo $a; // I'll &quot;walk&quot; the &lt;b&gt;dog&lt;/b&gt; now

echo $b; // I'll "walk" the <b>dog</b> now
```

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
 html_entity_decode()
```

instead of

```
 html_entity_encode()
```

Answer (score 5):

If you check the [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) manual:

> You might wonder why  trim(html_entity_decode(' ')); doesn't
> reduce the string to an empty string, that's because the ' '
> entity is not ASCII code 32 (which is stripped by trim()) but ASCII
> code 160 (0xa0) in the default ISO 8859-1 characterset.

You can nest your html_entity_decode() function inside a [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to ASCII #160 to a space:

```
<?php

echo str_replace("\xA0", ' ', html_entity_decode('ABC &nbsp; XYZ') );

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know my answer is coming in really late but thought it might help someone else.  I find that the best way to extract all special characters is to use [utf8_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) in php.  Even for dealing with `&nbsp;` or any other special character representing blank space use `utf8_decode()`.

After using `utf8_decode()` one can manipulate these characters directly in the code.  For example, in the following code, the function clean() replaces `&nbsp;` with a blank.  Then it replaces all extra white spaces with a single white space using `preg_replace()`. Leading and trailing white spaces are removed using `trim()`.

```
function clean($str)
{       
    $str = utf8_decode($str);
    $str = str_replace("&nbsp;", "", $str);
    $str = preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $str);
    $str = trim($str);
    return $str;
}

$html = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;Hello world! lorem ipsum.";
$output = clean($html);
echo $output;
```

> Hello world! lorem ipsum.