# Processing text and convert to string without removing the text format in php

Tags: arrays, text

I have the following text as inputText:

```
HEADER:This is title 1
HEADER:This is         title 2
HEADER:        This is title 3
```

I want to remove "HEADER:" and convert the text into long string and keep the text format(without remove the spaces) as sample below:

```
This is title 1      This is       title 2      This is title 3
```

Assuming the length for each line is fix to 30 character (include spaces). 
The following is my code.

```
$string = $this->input->post(inputText);

//move the string to array 
$Text = array($string);
$lines = count($Text);

$x=0;
while($x<=$lines)
{
   //Remove "HEADER:" Length is = 7
   $newText[$x] = array(substr($Text[$x],7));
   $x++;
}

$stringText = implode("\n",$newText);

echo $stringText;
```

But it seems this code is not working..

Comment: Have you checked that what $Text is returning. and what is the count coming

Comment: $text value is correct but seems the count is wrong.. it return value 1

Comment: your $text will be returning the whole string in one index. actually you are not able to explode the string correctly.

Comment: then i should explode first before remove the header then implode back?

Comment: i manage to get 3 lines after i explode $Text but i didnt get the output that i want.. spaces are all gone..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey Julie the problem was coming that the explode function was removing the white spaces in the string so

```
$string = str_replace(" ", "-", $string);
```

Now you will get your sub string with all white spaces would be replaced by **-**

```
$Texts = explode('HEADER:',$string);
foreach($Texts as $key=>$data)
{
  $Texts[$key] = str_replace('-',"&nbsp",$data);
}
```

By this you will have a array with sub strings you required in a array

**UPDATE**

```
$stringPhp = str_replace(" ", "-", $string);
$Texts = explode('HEADER:',$string);
$TextPHP = explode('HEADER:',$string);
foreach($TextPHP as $key=>$data)
    {
      $TextsPHP[$key] = str_replace('-',"&nbsp",$data);
    }
    //U can use $TextsPHP for you php I am sure it will not give you any troubles.

for html suppose you want to print $Texts[1] element.

<input type="text" value="<?php echo $Texts[1];" />
```

Now you will see that in html output, those blank spaces would be present

Comment: I'm stuck again.. after i do str_replace('-',"&nbsp",$data); my data contain as follows: This is title 1This is&nbsp&nbsp&nbsptitle 2&nbsp&nbsp&nbspThis is title 3

Comment: @Julie where whats the problem now

Comment: I didn't get what you are trying to say. please explain

Comment: This&nbspis&nbsptitle&nbsp1&nbspThis&bspis&title&2&nsp&This&nbspis&nbsptitle&nbsp3

Comment: i got this output instead spaces.. at my browser.. it shows spaces.. but in my output file.. it contain &nbsp

Comment: I found this but i'm not sure how it work.. i've tried but still not work for my code..  http://stackoverflow.com/a/26789995/5971854

Comment: Again use str_replace()in html

Comment: Hey Julie If you try then by only using the explode function you will be able to show the string as required by you in the html.. but if you have to use the string in your php code then try the above answer..

Comment: yes.. i need to use the string in my php code..then i output it in my output file as long string... means that i need to str_replace() in html?.. i dont get it..

Comment: i tried to str_replace ("&nbsp"," ",$Text) before process it.. and all spaces gone (only left 1 space).. but if i str_replace after processing, it effect my output..

Comment: Thanks a lot.. yeahh.. shud use 2 variable instead for this data.. for display and processing.. Thats really solve it.. :)